# Showing the expected value of $S_t^n$ where $S_t=S_0e^{(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+\sigma W_t}$

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes

The answer is $\mathbb{E}[S_t^n]=S_0^ne^{nrt+\frac{n(n-1)}{2}\sigma^2t}$. But I can't obtain this result.

First off, while this might be slightly disconnected to the question, "what is the distribution of $S_t$?" I heard it's log-normal.
But in a nutshell, what exactly is it's probability density function? I can't find a clear answer anywhere; I was told it has mean $\mu = \text{ln}S_0+(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})T$ and variance $\sigma^2T$ but am I to substitute these straight into the density function of a normal distribution, $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sigma \sqrt{2 \pi}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$?

Now to the question itself, my attempt,

> $S_0^n\mathbb{E}[e^{n(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+n\sigma x}]=S_0^n \frac{1}{ \sqrt{2 \pi}t} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{n(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+n\sigma x-\frac{x^2}{2t}}dx$ taking $f(x)$ as the normal density I stated above. Proceeding with the in the usual way, I end up with $S_0^ne^{nrt}$ simply the nasty looking terms of $n$ that I should get disappearing by cancellation.
>
> Specifically, I get $\frac{n \sigma^2t-n \sigma^2t}{2} = 0$

Either that 1. I made an error in my integration process 2. I used the wrong $f(x)$(density function) for integration.

Can someone please point out what I should be doing? Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First pull constant factors out of the expectation:
$$
S_0^n\mathbb{E}[e^{n(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t+n\sigma W_t}]=S_0^ne^{n(r-\frac{\sigma^2}2)t}\mathbb E e^{n\sigma W_t}
$$
You're now left with $\mathbb E e^{n\sigma W_t}$. Rather than carry around all those parameters, you can make your life easier by writing $n\sigma W_t = aZ$ where $Z$ has standard normal distribution and $a=n\sigma\sqrt t$. Now calculate:
$$
\mathbb E e^{aZ} = \int e^{az}\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-z^2/2}\,dz
= \int \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-[z^2-2az]/2}\,dz
= \int \frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-[(z-a)^2-a^2]/2}\,dz=e^{a^2/2}.
$$
Apply this with $a=n\sigma\sqrt t$ to obtain
$$
\mathbb Ee^{n\sigma W_t}=e^{(n\sigma\sqrt t)^2/2} = e^{n^2\sigma^2t/2}.
$$
Combining this with the factors pulled out earlier, the exponent will be
$$
n\left(r-\frac{\sigma^2}2\right)t+n^2\sigma^2t/2=nrt+\frac{\sigma^2t}2(n^2-n),
$$
as desired.

Comment: Hello, thanks for answering; one question for your answer. Isn't the expected value $\mathbb{E}$ we need is with respect to $t$? Is it with respect to $W_t$? I ask this as in the very first line, you took out the term with exponents $n(r-\frac{\sigma^2}{2})t$ Is our random variable $W_t$ and not $t$?

Comment: @JohnTrail My understanding is that $t$ is a constant. If $t$ were a RV, the expectation you're trying to calculate would have to end up being free of $t$. The only random component seems to be $W_t$.

Comment: I see, I'll have that in mind when solving similar problems in future, thank you!!